# How do I construct a function choosing i-th order of ordered pair?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A,B$ be sets.

Let $G\subset A\times B$.

Then how do I construct a function $f:G\rightarrow B$ such that $f(a,b)=b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that in such function $f$, the elements are ordered pairs $\langle z,y\rangle$, such that $z\in G\subseteq A\times B$. Namely, $z=\langle a,b\rangle$.

Now which $y$ do you need to take so the result is as you want it?

Comment: I meant to pick the second term in an ordered pair. So y=b

Comment: That is, how do I construct a "coordinate map"-like function for an ordered pair?

Comment: For $\prod X_i$, the coordinate map $\pi_i$ can be construced as $\pi_i(x)=x(i)$. Just like this, how do I construct a function $f:G\rightarrow B$ which picks the second term of ordered pairs?

Comment: What do you mean by "construct"? I told you how to write the set which defines the function (or its graph, if you will). I don't know what more you can do to "construct" a map.